# does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am reworking this code from Swift 3.0.

```
extension WallPost: PFSubclassing {

static func parseClassName() -> String { return "WallPost" } }
```

This generates the error:

> Type 'WallPost' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing'
> Unavailable class method 'object()' was used to satisfy a requirement of protocol 'PFSubclassing'

Any idea of why this is happening and how I can resolve it? I wanted to fix this before updating to Swift 4.0 / 5.0.

This is the code:

```
import Foundation

final class WallPost: PFObject {
  
  // MARK: - Properties
  @NSManaged var image: PFFile
  @NSManaged var user: PFUser
  @NSManaged var comment: String?
  
  // MARK: - Initializers
  init(image: PFFile, user: PFUser, comment: String?) {
    super.init()
    self.image = image
    self.user = user
    self.comment = comment
  }
  
  // Required otherwise the application crashes
  override init() {
    super.init()
  }
  
  // MARK: - Overridden
  override class func query() -> PFQuery<PFObject>? {
    let query = PFQuery(className: WallPost.parseClassName())
    query.includeKey("user")
    query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    return query
  }
}

// MARK: - PFSubclassing
extension WallPost: PFSubclassing {
  
  static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "WallPost"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what PFSubclassing is, perhaps share the code, otherwise this question doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: Sorry - here is the code...

Comment: That’s not the protocol …

Comment: Can you clarify?  What is the issue and how do I fix it?  Thanks1

Comment: The issue is that the error message complains about a protocol named PFSubclassing but you have not included the declaration of that protocol in the question or explained what it is and no one can help you without that knowledge.

Comment: Here is the protocol information

Comment: https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Protocols/PFSubclassing.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge on what parseplatform is but you have to implement following methods to satisfy protocol requirements.

+objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:

+query

+queryWithPredicate:

+registerSubclass